# Can I have two main panels from a single service drop?

Tags: electrical

Can I run 2 main panels both with separate circuits and main disconnects all off of 1 electrical service from the street?  basically separate 1st floor 2nd floor with different boxes and only one service.

Answer (score 5):

Your profile does not show where you are from. If you are in the US, then the answer is yes. The main electrical drop has to be sized for both panels and each panel should have its own utility meter. All NEC codes must be conformed to. You need to consult your local government to see about local codes as well.

Comment: And if you only want 1 meter, then maybe a sub-panel is more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can.  But the two main disconnects (i.e. main breakers) must be right next to each other *NEC 230.72(A)*, so as to satisfy the "Rule of Six". *NEC 230.71(A)*

They also must be very close to the meter since the **service entrance conductors** from the meter to the disconnect have no overcurrent protection.  That pretty much means "the other side of the wall" but varies by jurisdiction.